# Laravel : Creating default object from empty value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, edit, laravel-request

I have this following problem while trying to Edit data already existing in my database. 
my controller name is UserController.php

Error: Creating default object from empty value.

I can Pull data from my database and post it in my form. when trying editing that error occurs.
Here is the block of code that causes the error.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'fname' => 'required',
        'lname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'bday' => 'required',
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'access' => 'required'
    ]);
    $userList = users::find($id);
    $userList->fname = $request->get('fname');
    $userList->lname = $request->get('lname');
    $userList->email = $request->get('email');
    $userList->phone = $request->get('phone');
    $userList->address = $request->get('address');
    $userList->country = $request->get('country');
    $userList->city = $request->get('city');
    $userList->bday = $request->get('bday');
    $userList->username = $request->get('username');
    $userList->password = $request->get('password');
    $userList->access = $request->get('access');
    $userList->save();
    return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', 'Data Updated');


}
```

I can see from the debugger that I send the new data

```
GET Data empty
POST Data
_token   "mnC6GliLHdSazZkEpaxZQ97aAChr2LObcc9clMlk"
_method  "PATCH"
fname    "test"
lname    "user"
email    "test@user.lara"
phone    "12345678990"
address  "Streat"
country  "countryplace"
city     "somecity"
bday     "2018-01-01"
username     "tester"
password     "test"
access   "Client"
```

But It highlights  `$userList->fname = $request->get('fname');`
and says : "Creating default object from empty value"

I am new to laravel and  cant understand why this is happening.
is it because of my form?

```
  <form method="post" action="{{action('UserController@update','$id')}}">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
              <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
<form method="post" action="{{action('UserController@update','$id')}}">
```

You should not use quotes for `$id`, it should be:

```
<form method="post" action="{{action('UserController@update',$id)}}">
```

Now because you have quotes, in line:

```
$userList = users::find($id);
```

no user is found, because in fact it's doing:

```
$userList = users::find('$id');
```

Comment: Yes that was the case, I feel kinda ashamed to miss something like that. Thanks a lot